# SQL Statement (JOIN)

Tags: sql, mysql, join

I have the following MySql Table:

```
--------------------------------------------
Table 'category'
--------------------------------------------
category_id    name        parent_id
1              animal      NULL
2              vegetable   NULL
3              mineral     NULL
4              dog         1
6              cat         1
7              carrot      2
8              quartz      3
```

The following SQL Statement will list all results like this:

---

```
category_id    category    sub_category
4              animal      dog
6              animal      cat
7              vegetable   carrot
8              mineral     quartz

SELECT sub_category.category_id AS category_id,
       category.name AS category,
       sub_category.name AS sub_category
FROM category
LEFT OUTER JOIN category AS sub_category
    ON sub_category.parent_id = category.category_id
WHERE category.parent_id IS NULL
ORDER BY category_id
```

But now I have another table with categories that particular users are NOT interested in:

```
--------------------------------------------
Table 'category_filter'
--------------------------------------------
user_id   category_id
1         4
1         7
1         8
```

How can I make a query for one particular user so that I get a list of all categories with an info whether a user is interested or not?

Something like this for example:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
category_id    category    sub_category    interested
4              animal      dog             NULL
6              animal      cat             6
7              vegetable   carrot          7
8              mineral     quartz          NULL
```

Thanks in advance for your support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
   SELECT c.category_id,
          c.name AS category,
          subc.name AS sub_category,
          cf.category_id AS interested
     FROM CATEGORY c
LEFT JOIN CATEGORY subc ON subc.category_id = c.parent_id
                       AND subc.parent_id IS NULL
LEFT JOIN CATEGORY_FILTER cf ON cf.category_id IN (c.category_id, subc.category_id)
                            AND cf.user_id = ?
    WHERE c.parent_id IS NOT NULL
```

The join to `CATEGORY_FILTER` is different from @djacobson's answer, in that it joins the table to both instances of the `CATEGORY` table.

Comment: Unfortunately this one gets a list of the parent categories (animal, vegetable, mineral) instead of the subcategories.

Comment: @Mark Fischer: I missed a join criteria on the sub categories to ensure parents are not included, but the query would return sub categories.  Please try again with the updated statement.

Comment: Unfortunatly still the same results (only the parent categories).

Comment: @Mark Fischer: I had the join criteria backwards between the category and subcategory instances.  Please try now, it's working for me in my testing.

Comment: When I edit the last statement so that it is "WHERE c.parent_id IS NOT NULL" then I get a perfect list.  Thanks a lot

Comment: Actually I had to change it a bit. Thanks a lot for your support and here's the final Statement: SELECT category.category_id,
       parent_category.name AS category,
       category.name AS sub_category,
       filter.category_id AS interested
FROM category
LEFT JOIN category AS parent_category
    ON parent_category.category_id = category.parent_id
    AND parent_category.parent_id IS NULL
LEFT JOIN category_filter AS filter
    ON filter.category_id IN (category.category_id, parent_category.category_id)
    AND filter.user_id = 1
WHERE category.parent_id IS NOT NULL

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you just need to add another join to the query to include the filter:

```
SELECT sub_category.category_id AS category_id,
       category.name AS category,
       sub_category.name AS sub_category,
       filter.category_id AS interested
FROM category
LEFT OUTER JOIN category AS sub_category
    ON sub_category.parent_id = category.category_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM category_filter WHERE user_id = @UserID) filter ON category.category_id = filter.category_id
WHERE category.parent_id IS NULL
ORDER BY category.category_id
```

This will only pull the "interest" information for the given user, joining it to the set of all categories.

Comment: Unfortunately this statement doesn't get any results. What I'm looking for is that all categories are listed but that there is an additional column where i can see if the user is interested or not.

Comment: hmm, this one gets: Unknown column 'category_filter.category_id' in 'field list'

Comment: @Mark Fischer: I corrected the unknown column error, wasn't using the table alias.

Comment: Thanks a lot: Now I'm getting a list of all subcategories and a 'interested' columns (which is both fine). But the categories in which the user isn't interested have also the value NULL (like all other catgories).

Comment: @Mark Fischer: Yes, the NULL matches the output you listed--if the user doesn't have a filter association, the value will be NULL.